# psql returns 'anonymous' in results array

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm running the following psql on my node server:

```
SELECT json_data.key AS id, json_data.value::int AS version
FROM players.settings, json_each_text(players.settings.value) AS json_data
WHERE name = $1 AND json_data.value::int > 0;
```

The results returned include the string `anonymous` before each result object:

```
[ anonymous { id: '1ab56bd6-ef7d-4755-92d5-1b0cf7beb4b7', version: 1 },
anonymous { id: '4ea3d884-d2a6-4074-a094-a45f6003e6d4', version: 1 } ]
```

What am I missing here? I've never seen this anonymous string before and would like to get rid of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To my knowledge, you can't get rid of it, at least not on your side.

See: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1062

It's just a Node.js 6 new feature to report into the console when the object was created using an anonymous class.

You can safely ignore it ;)