# How to get count of entries in column grouped by this column in knex

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to translate the following SQL query to knex.js:

```
select name, count(name)
from mytable
group by name;
```

It returns:

```
name | count 
-----+-------
greg |     2
john |     1
```

I've tried:

```
knex
  .select(['name'])
  .count('name as count')
  .groupBy('name')
  .from('mytable');

// ...
// console.log(result)
```

The output is:

```
[ anonymous { name: 'greg', count: '2' },
  anonymous { name: 'john', count: '1' } ]
```

What's `anonymous`? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like there's nothing about grouping and countring. Even simple select in this particular place for some reason contains those "anonymous". Still truing to achieve wtf going on

Comment: About the `anonymous` part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530414/psql-returns-anonymous-in-results-array. And knex uses the same driver.

Comment: @vitaly-t well, thanks. I don't know that. It would be great if you post it as an  anwer so that I can accept it as correct

Comment: The title of your question got nothing to do with your question. And if it did, it would be marked as a duplicate. So really, no point answering.